# HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, api

Segue código:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
var result = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(new Uri("URL do Site ..."));
```

Veja o retorno:

> HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type Type Status Report
>
> Message Cannot consume content type
>
> Description The origin server is refusing to service the request
>   because the payload is in a format not supported by this method on the
>   target resource.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.23

Coloquei `"Accept", "application/json"` e mesma assim não funcionou. Me parece que está faltando colocar `application/json` no `DeleteAsync()`.

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei outra solução:

```
HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, "URL do Site ...")
{
    Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, boa tarde

Você deve especificar o método HTTP a que se refere, como por exemplo Http Delete, e se necessário, informar que as informações são via Body, ou query string e assim por diante:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Content = new StringContent("[YOUR JSON GOES HERE]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Delete,
    RequestUri = new Uri("[YOUR URL GOES HERE]")
};

await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Espero ter ajudado.